# Nuxtjs 3 server directory `api` throwing 404 with message "Cannot find any route matching /api/conversation."

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am using the server directory in Nuxtjs3 to register api endpoints and handle request and responce.

In the directory `server/api/conversation.post.ts` I have the code:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const { body } = await readBody(event)
    const sentPrompt = body.prompt

    return { data: sentPrompt}

  }
  catch (error: any) {
   //handle error here
  }
})
```

In the Nuxt app Pinia Stores I am making the request as:

```
    async fetchResponse() {
      try {

        const response = await $fetch(`/api/conversation`, { method: 'post', body: { prompt: this.prompt } })
        console.log(response)
      }
      catch (error: any) {
      }
    }
```

On the network tab, A request is being made to `http://localhost:3000/api/conversation` but unfortunately I get the error below.

Error :

```
{url: "/api/conversation", statusCode: 404,…}
message
: 
"Cannot find any route matching /api/conversation."
stack
: 
""
statusCode
: 
404
statusMessage
: 
"Cannot find any route matching /api/conversation."
url
: 
"/api/conversation"
```

Need some help here! Not sure what might be off.

I wanted to have server endpoints expose on `/api/conversation` and handle the request. I have tried axios but still getting the error. I have digged into the Docs but nothing fruitful.

Comment: try useFetch instead of $fetch and let me know if that worked!

Comment: Tried using useFetch and for some reason it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: Are you making that call within your pinia store? It looks like a life cycle issue to me, but I would need more details!

Comment: I bet you have a JS error in conversation.post.ts that's happening on the server side. That's usually what throws generic errors like this for me. Try changing const `{ body } = await readBody(event)` to const `body = await readBody(event);`.

Comment: Basically I found that something was off inside the async `defineHandler` function on `conversation.post.ts`.